# ASP.NET WebForm Loading GIF file response not hide

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response

I'm adding a gif which has name loading.gif and placed in the div that has id attribute with value of "loadingDiv" and which should be show up every time the click event fires. Show event of that "loadingDiv" div is triggered  at the same time sending request.

[image: request compile]

[image: It is expected to answer the request.]

When the respond comes, hide event is triggered and user can easily understand the process has reached the end by hiding that loadingDiv element.

This part of process performs perfect. However, if an event returns a document (like excel) downloading process fires and hide event can never perform.

I want loadingDiv to be hidden with ending process.

I added some pictures about my problem. I want to hide loadingDiv element when status gets out of pending state.

Thanks for your replies already.

Show Loading:

```js
$("input:image").click(function () {
    $("#LoadingDiv").show();
});
```

MasterForm Add Html Element

```
private void AddLoadingImage()
    {
        HtmlGenericControl NewControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        NewControl.ID = "LoadingDiv";
        NewControl.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image: url('../../common/images/477.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; width: 100%; height: 98%; position: absolute; top: 1px; display: none;");
        this.Form.Controls.Add(NewControl);
    }
```

Response:

```
myWorkbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(ms);
myWorkbook.Save (response, fileName, contentDisposition, saveOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to add a class like "file" to elements that will return a file. Then change your show function like this:

```
$("input:image").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("file")) {
        $("#LoadingDiv").show();
    }
});
```

That why if element will return a file loading gif will never show up and the default browser download window will trigger.

For another solution you could switch to use AJAX download and hide loading gif on the Success callback.

Comment: No it must operate at the file download process.My pages Ajax not support.